# Why can't I do a loop in sys.stdin two times in a row ? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdin, sys

First i need to get the number of lines and so i do :

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    c = c + 1
print("Number of lines:" + str(c))
A = [[] for x in range(0,c)]
print(A)
```

But then I need to enter again a `for line in sys.stdin:` because I need to read the input.

It does not work and the second time it is almost as the input was consumed and now is empty.

Comment: It's exactly that: The input is consumed and now empty. Why do you need the number of lines in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the stdin input in a variable:

```
lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
```

Now you can loop over the `lines` variable as many times as you like.

If you're just counting the lines you don't need a loop at all; you can just say `c = len(lines)`.

Answer (score 1):

You must the save the input if you want to access it multiple times. The first `for` loop consumes the stream, which is not seekable.

```
lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
```

If you're processing each line, you might prefer something like:

```
results = [foo(i) for i in sys.stdin]
print("Have {} results".format(len(results))
```

You can also use `enumerate` to keep a count:

```
for cnt, line in enumerate(sys.stdin, start=1):
    foo(line)

print('Saw {} lines'.format(cnt))
```